# Mobile Fix Wordpress Class Issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm currently working on a website at dev.dragonscaletech.com

I'm running into an issue with a certain class.

The code from the header is

```
<div id="mobilebgfix">
<div class="mobile-bg-fix-img-wrap">
    <div class="mobile-bg-fix-img"></div>
</div>
<div class="mobile-bg-fix-whole-site">
```

When I use google inspect, it is adding an inline style to the mobile-bg-fix-img. I can't find this anywhere in the css or code. Not sure where it is coming from.

```
<div class="mobile-bg-fix-img" style="width: 375px; height: 767px; background-size: auto; background-position: 50% 0%; background-repeat: repeat; background-image: url(&quot;http://dev.dragonscaletech.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Hero-Banner-No-Title.png&quot;);"></div>
```

I'm trying to make a class in my child theme for the following:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.mobile-bg-fix-img {
background-position: 150% 0% !important;
}
}
```

The browser seems to be ignoring the media query and changing the background position on any resolution.

I'm basically trying to position the image to a certain place on mobile vertical view only.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you checked to see if there isnt actually an inline style in the html?

Comment: The inline CSS is not in the code that I found in the header.php file that I copied to my child theme.

Answer (score 0):

Your `background-position` is indeed correctly applied at small widths, and your `!important` declaration will override the inline style:

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .mobile-bg-fix-img {
    background-position: 150% 0% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-bg-fix-img" style="width: 375px; height: 767px; background-size: auto; background-position: 50% 0%; background-repeat: repeat; background-image: url(&quot;http://dev.dragonscaletech.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Hero-Banner-No-Title.png&quot;);"></div>
```

If it is not applying on your site, then you either have some additional overriding logic with higher **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**, or you have cached the old CSS. Ensure you clear your CSS cache with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, and additionally clear your HTML cache with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.

The only other possible scenario is that you have not actually referenced your CSS file correctly. Ensure that the CSS file is being loaded by checking the `Sources` tab of the **[F12 Developer Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589512(v=vs.85).aspx)**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have refreshed my css on my mac with chrome using cmd + shift + r. The mobile inspect looks as I hoped, but the desktop view is taking the customization too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a child-theme and the core files of the template weren't copied to the child-theme folder it is possible this issue origin comes from this.

I would also check if it is not a .js script injecting the inline style.

Cheers!